# What's the difference between req.setTimeout & socket.setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, http, settimeout

I have two options to set a timeout to my http request. I am not sure about their difference.

First one is:

```
req.setTimeout(2000,function () {
  req.abort();
  console.log("timeout");
  self.emit('pass',message);
});
```

Second one is:

```
req.on('socket', function (socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(2000);  
  socket.on('timeout', function() {
      req.abort();
      self.emit('pass',message);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`socket.setTimeout` sets the timeout for the socket, e.g. to implement HTTP Keep-Alive.

`request.setTimeout` does internally call `socket.setTimeout`, as soon as a socket has been assigned to the request and has been connected. This is described in the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback).

Hence, it's no difference, and you can choose which way to go. Of course, if you already have a request in your hands, you'd stick to the request's `setTimeout` function instead of digging for the underlying socket.